# Wait until dialog is closed to add item to recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I have a `RecyclerView` that should get a new item with a name set in an `AlertDialog`. 
The problem is that the item is getting created while the dialog is still open in the below code. 
How can I wait for the input in this case? If I have to hook in `onDismiss()` I do not have the `RecyclerView` info that I need to set the name of the correct item.

```
    HouseConfig config = new HouseConfig(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter new Category name");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_text = input.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    Log.v(TAG,"m_text: " + m_text);
    config.addNewCategoryWithViewOrder(new Category(m_text, R.drawable.ic_books, -1));
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.getParent().getParent().getParent();
    rv.setAdapter(new CategoryRecycleListAdapter(config.getViewOrderSortedCategories(), this));
    rv.scrollToPosition(config.getCategorySize() - 1);
    rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(config.getCategorySize() - 2, 1);
    rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick()` method of Positive button is called when you press the 'OK' button. So you should add new data in this method and notify the adapter.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        m_text = input.getText().toString();
        config.addNewCategoryWithViewOrder(new Category(m_text, R.drawable.ic_books, -1));
        rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(config.getCategorySize() - 2, 1);  // I would rather used notifyItemInserted()
        rv.scrollToPosition(config.getCategorySize() - 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the logic of creating new Item inside onClick method. In this case new Item is created right after dialog opens (with previous m_text i guess).

Answer (score 0):

in your on create you can initialize or setup your recycler view and when you want to add new item in that recycler view you can do it in onclick of the dialog.

```
//function which setup RV.
initializeRV() //call this function in onCreate function.
showPopup() // call this function after initializeRV function.

public void showPopup(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter new Category name");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            updateView(input.getText().toString());
            dialog.dismiss();
}
});
}
builder.create().show();
public void updateView(String data){
//initialize your that particular (HoseConfig)item here, add it to list and notify RV adpter.
//after creating config object
config.addNewCategoryWithViewOrder(new Category(m_text, R.drawable.ic_books, -1));
        rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(config.getCategorySize() - 2, 1);  // I would rather used notifyItemInserted()
        rv.scrollToPosition(config.getCategorySize() - 1);
}
public void initializeRV(){
//setup your Recycler View adapter and manager here!!
    }
```